# ASP.Net popup for Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, popupwindow

I cannot seem to get Chrome to pop up an "alert" page.  The alert page has code in it, so it can't really be a DIV or I would just do it that way.  It worked for many years, but likely do to a Chrome update it will no longer function.  Still works fine in IE11, though.

The following code is used to pop up an "alert" page when there is an alert that is queried from a Database.  It has always worked until recently (15 years and running)

CODE:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "Alarm", "<script language='javascript'>window.showModalDialog('Alarm.aspx?ID=" & AlarmID & "', null, 'dialogWidth=460px;dialogHeight=310px;status=no;resizable=yes');document.frmA.submit();</script>")
```

I've tried a few things like windows.open and creating a hidden button on the asp.net page and then using the click event.  Nothing works.  I do not see a blocked popup in Chrome and I have even went into settings and did the following:

- Set Safe Browsing to "No Protection"
- Set allow pop-ups and redirects on the server name (http://servername and http://localhost)

Comment: That method has been removed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

Answer (score 0):

As noted, near all browsers quite much have clamped down on popup windows. this makes things more difficult for web developers.

There are two good approaches. one I don't fancy at all is using bootstrap dialogs, but they tend to "sort of work all on their own" kind of deal based on class settings for divs etc. - really hard to debug.

Since near all sites these days include jQuery for your js code, then I quite much hands down recommend you introduce jquery.UI. It has a whole slew of nice things such as date pickers etc. But it also has a rather nice dialog pop option. They just work, and when you code them up? They follow "normal" like code approaches.

it not quite clear if your message/dialog pops after say a button click (and post back), and the at the end of that process, you need/want some dialog message to display. But all in all, I would high recommend jQuery.UI for this dialog/message that you need.

jQuery.UI in most cases expects the content you want to "display/pop" exists in a simple div in the current existing page. However, it also works VERY well if you supply the dialog another existing web page. The only REAL big issue to keep in mind? That dialog page you pop cannot handle multiple post-backs. (so, some buttons, or ONE post back in that dialog is fine - but you ONLY get the ONE post-back.
So, if that page display allows some input, or some interaction and ONLY requires ONE post-back, then jQuery.UI is again great. If that pop page requires several buttons and several post-backs, then you are in for a world of pain and hurt - jQuery.UI dialogs (like most) cannot survive or handle multiple postbacks. Any post-back means the dialog closes (collapses). So in those cases, you have to adopt ajax calls (web methods) if you need/have/want that page to have more then one active post-back button or event.

So, you could have/place a script in even your master page, and little function code stub that your register script can call.

Or, I suppose you could inject the whole script, but the script would look like this:

So, the pop page actualy is SHOVED into a div. So we have a div that "holds" the page.

The jQuery.UI code script then looks like this:

```
 <div id="poppagearea">

 </div>
    <script>
        function showpage() {

            var mydiv = $('#poppagearea');
            mydiv.dialog({
                autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'My cool other page', width: '30%',
                position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                buttons: {
                    'ok': function () {
                     mydiv.dialog('close');
                     alert('user click ok');
                    },
                    'cancel': function () {
                        mydiv.dialog('close');
                        alert('user click cancel');
                    }
                }
            });
            mydiv.load('Default.aspx');
            // Open the dialog
            mydiv.dialog('open');
        }
```

So, in above, we loaded "default.aspx" into that dialog and thus displayed it on the page.

So, I would consider jQuery.UI - but it does mean adopting a new js library into your existing project.

The pop page does gray out the full page, and you do get a title bar, and your own ok, cancel button. The above thus looks like this:

[image]

So, it does a great job - but as noted, that page can only have one post-back, and it can't be a general working aspx page with lots of buttons and post backs - but it will render and display rather well.

Comment: yeah, the page I'm popping up has quite a few postbacks :(  There are up to 4 comboboxes (each requiring postback and update from database), up to 3 textboxes, and 2 buttons :(

I wish I knew why Chrome DID work for so long and now no longer doesn't. I didn't notice any Chrome updates that could have caused it.  They were on version 89.

Comment: oh darn! - at least I warned about this issue - would have hated to send you on a wild goose chase. -- you have to use ajax calls + web methods, or gasp - navigate to that page - let user chose and then go back. You could check timing on your page. I believe that windows are allowed if they are the result of a user click on that page - (not say a injected script manager idea. So you could drop a button on the page as a test - see if a  html + click to run some JS scrip  to launch the page works. so user clicks ARE supposed to still be allowed - not pages launched by js (it knows the difference

Comment: in other words a button to launch the window may well still work. What changed is that the js code alone that runs can't just be running and THEN decide to launch the window anymore. But a button click + js code to open the window is allowed (I think they use timing to determine this).  So a click a button to open the window is to my knowledge still supposed to work (it has to be a client side button + click event - not a code behind or a injected code behind script that runs after the page loads).

Comment: I may try that... I am currently giving this a try:  https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog/blob/gh-pages/showModalDialog.js.  It is working, but now I have to figure out how to close the dialog from the iFrame. If I can't get that to work, I will try the button.  I did try something like that early on, but may have given up too quickly :)  Thanks!